# How to prevent a sophisticated attacker from being able to tell your app is powered by Express.js in production?

Tags: node.js, express, security

I am looking to run an express.js app in production, and the last thing I want is for anyone to know that it is powered by express.js or node in general. I read this article:

https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html

and know for certain I need to remove the X-Powered-By (whether I use Helmet or not).

What bothers me is the statement in the article that says:

> Note: Disabling the X-Powered-By header does not prevent a
>   sophisticated attacker from determining that an app is running
>   Express. It may discourage a casual exploit, but there are other ways
>   to determine an app is running Express.

What other ways can an attacker detect an express.js app running and how can I protect against this?

Comment: This seems like a fruitless endeavor.  So what if they think you may be using Express?  Don't you need to just protect against vulnerabilities?  Probably more germaine is that they can detect that you're using node.js and its TCP classes (used by Express) and there's likely no way you can detect various fingerprinting techniques for that because any given TCP implementation will have some recognizable behaviors.  That's probably more germaine because vulnerabilities are much, much more likely to be there than in Express.  Express works at the app and request level, not at the TCP level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/expressjs/express/pull/2813#issuecomment-159270428) comment might interest you. I've copy-pasted the points below:

> Common methods to detect if a server is running Express
>
> 1. Are there response headers all in lower-case? The more there are, the more points assigned as likely being Node.js server, which in turn counts towards Express.js.
> 2. Some requests to random URLs are made looking for a 404. If the response body is in the format "Cannot GET {url}" then it gives a massive number of points towards it being Express.js. This is actually the main give away it uses to know you are an Express.js server.
> 3. What does the ETag header look like if there is one? There are definitions for the different versions of the ETag header format for Express.js, so this header matching certain formats not only gives points towards being Express.js, but even hints at the version of Express.js you are using, since the format has changed over time (even the X-Powered-By header doesn't provide that level of detail, since it does not contain a version).

Answer (score 0):

As explained on the [official website](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html), there are many things to do :

Here is the main extract, the full list of recommandations is on the link I gave you.

**Use Helmet**

```
var helmet = require('helmet')
app.use(helmet())
```

**At a minimum, disable X-Powered-By header**

```
app.disable('x-powered-by')
```